# share python multiprocessing.Queue between processes started seperately

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, shared-memory, python-3.8

I have a service implemented via python which is executed indefinetly and doing various stuff.
Now i have different "clients" that execute one shot tasks and therefore want to communicate with the service (pass data). This is done to let me update the code of clients without stopping the central service, so that other clients continue.
For that I would like to use the convinience of multiprocessing.Queue to pass complex python objects, as this works great when starting processes together, is fast and deals with mutexing access perfectly.

Is there some way to do this?

I know about multiprocessing.shared_memory which can be used to create named data maps which can be shared by name, which would be useable. But this has a lot of downsides as one has to write a library for pickling the data, mutexing access, signaling queue states for blocking till data is passed ect. which all have loads of possible pitfalls. multiprocessing. queue deals with all of that out of the box...
Thanks!

Comment: Alternately, consider zeromq which allows to you assemble more complex topologies. There are lots of other queuing systems out there too.

Comment: you can connect to a multiprocessing.manager process in a localhost process and get a proxy to a shared queue

Comment: i looked into multiprocessing.manager but did not get how i could interact with the same manager from another python execution, but mabe I did oversee something... could you point me to any resources that describe how that may be done?

Comment: the ["using a remote manager"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager) section has almost exactly your use case as an example. Managers talk over TCP, so it can even be on a different computer (as long as you set up the address correctly). Leaving the address blank means to use localhost address, and then just pick a port not in use for your "server" to use

Comment: Thank you! I somehow missed that part completely :/   This may be exactly what I need!

Comment: you mention speed in your post, and ysk that managed proxies are slower than their native counterparts. Args have to be pickled and sent to the server process where execution actually happens (even with locks). If you need for example a shared lock that will be used with significant frequency (like 100's to 1000's of times a second) there are ways on all major operating systems to get a system level shared mutex by name. (`posix-ipc` on posix systems... idk about windows other than win32 api)

Comment: also pickling custom class instances often requires the class be imported by both processes on either end of the pickle (client and server) idk if pickle / managers are smart about handling this